# Event studies: Panel OLS vs cross sectional OLS vs FE

Tags: regression, least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

[image]I'm currently working on my bachelor's thesis, where I'm investigating the effect of surprise interest rate decisions on stock prices using an event study approach similar to Bernanke and Kuttner (2005) (Link: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2005.00760.x ). My sample consists of approximately 60 rate decisions between 2011-2019, and 47 stocks in 9 different sectors. I use a narrow event window of 1 day which should exclude most potential omitted variable bias.

The variables are as follow:

Dependent variable in both cases is abnormal returns; independent variables are expected and unexpected interest rate changes, a QE dummy and a dummy for directionality (positive or negative surprise). Dependent variable is log transformed. I'm using closing price for the day prior to the rate decision and closing price the same day as interest rate decision. The calculation is then Price at T minus price at T-1. The result is further divided into a normal and an abnormal component (which can be done in different ways).

Picture shows how I have structured my data in excel. Example: For the panel, sectors are placed in rows to match each date. In other words, the picture continues with financials and once 60 observations are reached, it continues as telecom and so on. IRexp (expected rate change) and IRUnexp (unexpected) are used as independent variables in the panel, just not included in this picture, In the "cross section OLS" picture, abnormal return is indicated under each sector column. I should note that in both cases, the stocks' individual returns are used as an input (rather than an average of them)

I have run 3 different analyses using the same model; one using cross sectional OLS, one panel OLS and one fixed effects OLS. I get the same coefficient for all methodologies, although slightly different standard errors (and thus also T statistics).

1. I'm confused as to why this is, especially since the data input is organized differently (in the Excel files that I export to Eviews) in the different regressions.

This is what I have done:

A. Create an excel file with separate stock returns on dates of interest rate returns. Then I take stocks from the same sector and run a panel OLS.

B. Create an excel file with separate stock returns on dates of interest rate returns. Then I take stocks from the same sector and run a panel FE OLS.

C. Create an excel file with separate stock returns on dates of interest rate returns. Then I pool these together and run a regular OLS regression.

2. In addition, I'm not sure whether or not to treat my data as panel or not (even though I understand that having multiple entities with the same cross section sample over time is longitudinal) as I'm not particularly interested in any time trends.

Is my data input incorrectly specified? Does the similar results imply that there does not seem to be any time invariant unobservable heterogeneity in my data?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I should mention that I have tried to look for posts with similar questions for hours, but have not come across any such yet

Comment: There are some things that are not entirely clear.  Is it possible for you to include an example of how your data is structured, exact specification of your dependent variable, a description of what your panel variables are, and commands you used to run these models?  Also, I am not familiar with the paper you referenced (do you have a link?), but how is it possible to identify the effect if you only use stock return data on the days of of interest rate decisions?  Does your data show changes in returns for the same stock or sector following each decision?

Comment: Don't have access to Eviews at the moment so will post commands tomorrow.

As for how the data is structured I have attached two images to my original post showing how the data is structured in excel when exported to Eviews for both panel and cross section analysis. Dependent variable in both cases is abnormal returns; independent variables are expected and unexpected interest rate changes, a QE dummy and a dummy for directionality (positive or negative surprise).

For the panel, sectors are placed in columns to match each date. In other words, the picture continues with financials

Comment: and once 60 observations are reached, it continues as telecom and so on.

Dependent variable is log transformed.

I was a bit fast on describing my method: I'm using closing price for the day prior to the rate decision and closing price the same day as interest rate decision. The calculation is then Price at T minus price at T-1. The result is further divided into a normal and an abnormal component (which can be done in different ways).

My apologies; the paper can be found here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2005.00760.x 

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not seeing the images yet.  "For the panel, sectors are placed in columns to match each date" - would like to see what this means, how can sectors match dates?

Comment: Images up now!

Correction; for the panel, sectors are placed in rows to match each date (please see attached picture), IRexp (expected rate change) and IRUnexp (unexpected) are used as independent variables in the panel, just not included in this picture,

In the "cross section OLS" picture, abnormal return is indicated under each sector column. 

I should note that in both cases, the stocks' individual returns are used as an input (rather than an average of them)

Best regards

Comment: I don't know eViews, but organization of data (long of wide) should not matter if software understands what the organization is. So there does not appear to be any difference between "panel OLS" and "cross section OLS".  If the variables are the same in both models (without any additional fixed effects), you'll get the same results.  The only thing you said about FE is "Then I take stocks from the same sector and run a panel FE OLS".  It sounds like you are taking a subset of the full dataset, which does not go with estimating fixed effects.

Comment: Please move all relevant info from comments to the body of the question and go through the text and check that everything is described fully, concisely, and accurately.

Comment: Hmm, ok. If I understand correctly, my excel data structure should be fine? Any advice/links regarding how I should continue in order to figure out whether it makes a differece if my data is treated as cross section as opposed to panel, when running the regressions?

An additional question; in the paper I cited, they do not comment whether they treat their data as cross section or longitudinal. Is it safe to assume they use panel OLS because of the study design? (section 1B). Best regards

Comment: I don't think notable papers like this one use panel data without using fixed effects or something else that models repeated measures.  You should check what the data structure should be for your software.  I still don't fully understand what data and variables you use for each regression and what commands you use to run these models and it is hard to continue this discussion through this forum.  I recommend that you find somebody you can talk to face to face.  Good luck.

Comment: I understand. Followed your advice and was able to get in touch with an expert in the area face to face. Again; many thanks for your time and advice! Have a great day